# iText DataMatrix barcode resolution and quality

Tags: java, itext, barcode

I'm trying to insert Data Matrix barcodes in a PDF using iText. This is kind of working, but the image quality is not good enough. Is it somehow possible to increase the image size and resolution?

Example of my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx3LO.jpg

```
BarcodeDatamatrix dm = new BarcodeDatamatrix();
dm.generate("1234567890");
Image img = dm.createImage();
cell = new PdfPCell(img, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The barcode is created as a vector image, so the resolution is sharp no matter at which zoom factor you display it:

[image]

If the example of your input is a scan of a printed document, you've used a viewer that applied degraded printing. That's a problem you need to solve at the level of the viewer, because iText is rendering the image to the PDF in a resolution-independent way.

For the sake of completeness, this is the code I used to create the PDF in the screen shot:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("datamatrix.pdf"));
document.open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
table.setTotalWidth(100);
table.setLockedWidth(true);
table.addCell("1");
BarcodeDatamatrix dm = new BarcodeDatamatrix();
dm.generate("1234567890");
Image img = dm.createImage();
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img, false);
cell.setPadding(2);
table.addCell(cell);;
document.add(table);
document.close();
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the Firefox internal PDF viewer that didn't display it correctly. Switching to Adobe Acrobat solved it.